# After adding an additional binding to IIS Express, traffic to localhost is refused

Tags: iis-express, browserstack

After adding the binding `*:44335:bs-local.com` to my `applicationhost.config` and adding a urlacl rule with netsh, IIS Express no longer serves localhost:44334.  I would like to use both bindings in IIS Express.  How can this be achieved?

applicationhost.config

```
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61450:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44334:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44335:bs-local.com" />          
    </bindings>
```

To get IIS Express to serve bs-local.com, I do the following:

`netsh http add urlacl url=https://bs-local.com:44335/ user=everyone`

Once the urlacl has been updated, IIS will no longer serve localhost:44334.  It does not even show up in the list of running sites.  After running `netsh http delete uralcl url=https://bs-local.com:44335/` and restarting IIS Express, IIS Express will serve the site on localhost once again.

I have also added a self-signed cert for bs-local.com.

Answer (score 1):

Now, somehow it works.  My best guess is that in one of the iterations of configuration changes, things were put into the bad state.  I am not sure why it didn't work, or what I did that fixed it. I took the following since posting this:

- Removed the binding
- restarted visual studio
- removed the urlacl role for bs-local:44335
- Added the binding back
- Restarted Visual Studio, restarted IIS

IIS started with both sites enabled.